# Enable XLA when using tf.contrib.learn.Estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Seeing the [TF Dev Summit talk](https://youtu.be/kAOanJczHA0) on the potential (and highly experimental) benefits of turning on XLA on TensorFlow graphs, I thought I'd experiment with it a bit.

**Question**: When using [`tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn), how do I enable [JIT XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit#turning_on_jit_compilation)?

I can flag certain ops for JIT XLA by

```py
with tf.device("/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0"):
    output = tf.add(input1, input2)
```

However, the docs warn that this is meant just for testing. I'd like to be able to do this using the recommended way

```
# Config to turn on JIT compilation
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

but I can't figure out a way of setting the `tf.Session` from outside the `model_fn`.

This pseudo-code may clarify the problem better:

```
def char_cnn_model(features, target, mode, params, model_dir):
    # do stuff to build the CNN

    ...

    return tf.contrib.learn.ModelFnOps(mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions_dict,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

def main(unused_argv):
    # load training data, test data etc

    ...

    classifier = learn.Estimator(
        model_fn=char_cnn_model,  # defined above
        model_dir=model_dir,
        params=params,
        config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=60,
                                          log_device_placement=True,
                                          tf_random_seed=7))
    classifier.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        steps=5000,
        monitors=[validation_monitor])  # validation_monitor defined in main

    accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test)
```

[`tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig.md) seemed like a good candidate but it doesn't have something for the session (which I guess makes sense, why would the RunConfig have a pointer to the existing session?)

I could be overthinking this and [`tf.get_default_session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_session) could be all I need but can I modify the config of session after it's created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like not yet. The [MonitoredSession is being instantiated directly](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f821ce046df71f5784ed4ce7fb6b87f77d96b031/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L962) and the options are passed locally. 
Your only option would be to subclass and override the train method with a monitored session that uses the XLA configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's possible via `session_config` param of [RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig#session_config).
Here's an example:

```
session_config = tf.ConfigProto()                                               
optimizer_options = session_config.graph_options.optimizer_options               
if xla:                                                     
    optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1           

run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(                                        
    session_config=session_config,  # use this session config
    log_device_placement=True                                           
)                                                                           

base_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(                                   
    model_fn=model_fn,                                                      
    model_dir=model_dir,                                                    
    config=run_config,                                                      
    params=model_params                                                                
)
```